# Exception Class aborted(6) in Delphi XE8 deploying to iPhone

Tags: ios, delphi, mobile, delphi-xe8

I have a mobile app written in Delphi XE8 over Windows 7. It compiled and ran on my iPhone Last Friday. Over the weekend I upgraded my iOS version to 9.0.1.
This morning (Monday) I am getting the error message: 'Project Exception Class aborted(6).

The project compiles and builds fine, but when I try to deploy the app to my iPhone the exception occurs at:

```
FSharedContext := TEAGLContext.Wrap(TEAGLContext.Create.initWithAPI(kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2));
```

of

```
class procedure TCustomContextIOS.CreateSharedContext;
begin
  if FSharedContext = nil then
  begin
    FSharedContext := TEAGLContext.Wrap(TEAGLContext.Create.initWithAPI(kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2));
    TEAGLContext.OCClass.setCurrentContext(FSharedContext);
  end;
end;
```

in the unit FMX.Context.GLES.iOS

Could this be caused from the iOS version update or could something else have gone wrong? The other posts I found regarding this issue appear to have something to do with deploying to android but I am using an iPhone.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply a patch manually to target iOS 9 with XE8. There is a blog post describing the steps: [Steps for building iOS 32-bit applications for iOS 9 with XE7 and XE8](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/workaround-steps-for-building-ios-32-bit-applications-for-ios-9-with-xe7-and-xe8). It boils down to change the `Create` to an `Alloc` in line 52 of FMX.Context.GLES.iOS.pas using a local copy of that file.

```
FSharedContext := TEAGLContext.Wrap(TEAGLContext.Alloc.initWithAPI(kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2));
```

Comment: That fixed it. I had googled 'ios 9.0.1 XE8' and this solution did not come up. If I had googled 'ios 9 XE8' it would have been the first hit. Thanks for your help Uwe.